# Blender 2.8 Python Addon: How to register a Button?

Tags: python

I want to achieve a simple button (including the possibility to map a shortcut to it) to toggle the automerge option on and off.
Obviously this is wrong:

```
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh.append(toggle_automerge_button)
```

But, how to find the right register_class?

I am sure one could define a shortcut in the preferences, but for several reasons I'm interested in this add-on solution:

- I'm trying to learn Python.
- This is supposed to work as an example to include other things later.
- an extra button provides the possibiltity to put it in the Q-menu

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Toggle Automerge",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Mesh",
    "description": "Toggles Automerge on and off",
    "category": "Mesh",
}

import bpy

def toggle_automerge(self, context):

    if bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_mesh_automerge is False:
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_mesh_automerge = True
    else:
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_mesh_automerge = False

class ToggleAutomergeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
#class ToggleAutomergeOperator(bpy.types.ToolSettings):
#class bpy.types.ToolSettings(bpy_struct):
#class HelloWorldOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
#class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Toggle Automerge"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.toggle_automerge"
    bl_label = "Toggle Automerge"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):

        toggle_automerge(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'}

# Registration

def toggle_automerge_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        ToggleAutomergeOperator.bl_idname,
        text="Toggle Automerge",
        icon='PLUGIN')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ToggleAutomergeOperator)
    #bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    #bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh.append(toggle_automerge_button)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ToggleAutomergeOperator)
    #bpy.utils.unregister_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    #bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh.remove(toggle_automerge_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

**`wm.context_toggle`**

For a simple toggle of a boolean property with a context path can use the `bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="")` operator.  For the example in question

```
data_path = "scene.tool_settings.use_mesh_automerge"
```

To add as a layout element

```
op = layout.operator("wm.context_toggle")
op.data_path = "scene.tool_settings.use_mesh_automerge"
```

Removes the need to write an operator simply to toggle a property.

```
import bpy

def toggle_automerge_button(self, context):
    op = self.layout.operator(
        "wm.context_toggle",
        text="Toggle Automerge",
        icon='PLUGIN')
    op.data_path = "scene.tool_settings.use_mesh_automerge"

def register():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.append(toggle_automerge_button)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.remove(toggle_automerge_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note could also simply set the property

```
def toggle_automerge_button(self, context):
    ts = context.scene.tool_settings
    layout = self.layout
    layout.prop(ts, "use_mesh_automerge", toggle=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general feedback:

- Don't use `x is False`, use `x == False` instead, or even better `not x`.
- In an operator, always use the passed-in context instead of `bpy.context`.
- Don't pass any parameters you're not using (in this case `self`).
- You can simplify some code.

```
def toggle_automerge(context):
    ts = context.scene.tool_settings
    ts.use_mesh_automerge = not ts.use_mesh_automerge
```

The class should be named `MESH_OT_toggle_automerge`. This is standard naming in Blender; the class name should follow the `bl_idname`.

`bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh` indeed doesn't exist in Blender 2.80 any more, but since you don't give any indication as to where you want the button to show, it's hard to give an alternative. Maybe `bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view`?

If you want to learn Python, check out [Scripting for Artists](https://cloud.blender.org/p/scripting-for-artists) and [The Little Book of Python Anti-Patterns](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/).

Comment: Any ideas on how to add item to the quick favorites menu.?

Comment: @batFINGER I looked at the Blender sources, and there doesn't seem to be any way to do that from Python. Managing the quick favourites is really up to the user.